# jQuery each loop is not working

Tags: jquery

I put together some code based off reading some other stackoverflow questions and tested it in a fiddle and it works [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b3SD5/1/)

Tried to implement it in a clearFix function in my project (at the bottom) and I cant get it to work. I tried putting it in numerous places but it didnt change anything. Even placed some console logs along the code to see where it gets to and it never fires that function. I just want to insert a clearfix div every 3 divs that have the class col-md-3.

I'm sure my lack of knowledge I have something wrong. I am just starting to learn and piece code together. Here is my code -

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    window.insta = {

        apiUrl: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=[token goes here]&callback=?',

        grams: {},

        init: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: insta.apiUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: insta.success
            });
        },

        renderGrams: function (grams) {
            $.each(grams, function(index, gram) {
                insta.grams[gram.id] = gram;
                var gramHtml = '<div class="col-md-3"><p><img class="img-circle" style="margin-right: 5px" width="60" src="' + gram.user.profile_picture + '">' + gram.user.username + '</p><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-media-id="' + gram.id +'">';
                if (gram.type === 'image') { gramHtml = gramHtml + '<img class="img-thumbnail" src="' + gram.images.low_resolution.url + '"/>'; }
                if (gram.type === 'video') { gramHtml = gramHtml + '<video class="img-thumbnail" src="' + gram.videos.low_resolution.url + '"/>'; }
                gramHtml = gramHtml + '</a></div>';
                $('.results').append(gramHtml);
            });
        },

        setupClickEvent: function () {
            $('a').click(function(){
                var mediaId = $(this).data('mediaId'),
                    gram = insta.grams[mediaId],
                    largeImage = gram.images.standard_resolution.url,
                    username = gram.user.username,
                    tags = gram.tags,
                    comments = '';

                $('.modal-title').html(username);
                $('.modal-body').html('<div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + largeImage + '"><div class="tagwrap">' + tags + '</div></div>');


                $.each(gram.comments.data, function(index, comment){
                    comments += '<p>' + comment.text + '</p>';
                });

                $('.modal-body').append('<div class="comment-container">' + comments + '</div>');
            });
        },

        success: function (responseData) {
            if (responseData.meta.code === 200) {
                insta.renderGrams(responseData.data);
                insta.setupClickEvent();
            } else {
                $('.results').html('<h1>An Error Occured</h1><p>' + responseData.meta.error_message + '</p>');
            }
        },

        clearFix: function () {
            $('.col-md-3').each(function(i,val){
                i++;
                if(i%3===0){
                    $(this).append('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
                }
            });
        },
    };

    // This actually fires fires everything off
    // Follow from here
    insta.init();
}());
```

Comment: Nope, not too familiar with their API so I'm not much help TBH. Just thought I spotted an obvious flaw which apparently wasn't true. *deleting prior comments as they are irrelevant to your question.**

Comment: Where is that function being called from? (Or, figure out where you *want* to call it from, and actually call it!)

Comment: Well i thought it would just run, forgive my ignorance haha. I am struggling here. I am reading the docs again to see if it will click in my brain.

Comment: Try putting the call to `clearFix` in your `success` function, which it appears is called from `init()`.